# Change data-policy of Geode Region

Tags: gemfire, geode

I have just started to explore Geode Redis Adaptor. I want the region that holds Redis data to persist data to disk and make it available on server restart. I want the data-policy to be "partition_persistent_overflow". Is there a way to configure this? 
I tried doing:

```
start server --name=<name> --redis-port=<port> --redis-bind-address=<host> --J=-Dgemfireredis.regiontype=PARTITION_PERSISTENT_OVERFLOW
```

That didn't help.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you see when you run the command? what's not working? if you have gfsh try `describe region --name=<region_name>` and give the output

Comment: I see the data policy as REPLICATE for __ReDiS_MeTa_DaTa and normal for __StRiNgS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to store strings i.e. if you want to change the attributes of the __StRiNgS region, there is currently no way to do that. There is a [JIRA and a patch available](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-1921), but the fix will be included in 1.0 release.

For other data structures, it works as expected. I started a server using:

```
gfsh>start server --name=serv1 --redis-port=11211 --redis-bind-address=localhost --J=-Dgemfireredis.regiontype=PARTITION_PERSISTENT_OVERFLOW
```

Then started the redis cli and created a list:

```
127.0.0.1:11211> LPUSH mylist "world"  
(integer) 1
(3.33s)
127.0.0.1:11211> LPUSH mylist "hello"
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:11211>
```

Which creates a `mylist` region is Geode which gfsh describes as:

```
gfsh>describe region --name=/mylist
..........................................................
Name            : mylist
Data Policy     : persistent partition
Hosting Members : serv1

Non-Default Attributes Shared By Hosting Members

  Type   |        Name        | Value
-------- | ------------------ | --------------------
Region   | size               | 4
         | data-policy        | PERSISTENT_PARTITION
Eviction | eviction-action    | overflow-to-disk
         | eviction-algorithm | lru-heap-percentage
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to change __StRiNgS.